# AJAX with sql query ignoring the blank fields in submitted form

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I would like to use AJAX to send data from a form to my php page which will query a database and return an html table in order to refresh the main page with requested data.

All of this will be done in "real-time" : When you finish completing a field in the form, all of the data are refreshed. So I will have an AJAX request with new a new SQL request and new data will be returned.

**Problem : How to ignore blank fields in my request in php file?**

My code for the SQL request (I know how to do AJAX + return HTML) :

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM voyages WHERE villeChargement = :villeChargement AND villeLivraison = :villeLivraison AND debutChargementReel = :debutChargementReel AND
  finChargementReel = :finChargementReel AND numeroCommande = :numeroCommande AND numeroOT = :numeroOT');
$req->execute(array(
    'villeChargement' => $_POST['villeChargement'], //Yes but... If the field was blank??
    'villeLivraison' => $_POST['villeLivraison'], //Yes but... If the field was blank??
    'debutChargementReel' => $_POST['debutChargementReel'], //Yes but... If the field was blank??
    'finChargementReel' => $_POST['finChargementReel'], //Yes but... If the field was blank??
    'numeroCommande' => $_POST['numeroCommande'], //Yes but... If the field was blank??
    'numeroOT' => $_POST['numeroOT'] //Yes but... If the field was blank??
));
```

The HTML with inputs fields :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                <label>Ville de chargement</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="rechercheVilleChargement" placeholder="Chargement" id="rechercheVilleChargement">
                <label>Ville de livraison</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="rechercheVilleLivraison" placeholder="Livraison" id ="rechercheVilleLivraison">
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                <label>Chargement mini</label>
                <input type="text" id="debutChargementMini" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutChargementMini" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                <label><-></label>
                <input type="text" id="finChargementMini" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finChargementMini" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                <label>Chargement réel</label>
                <input type="text" id="debutChargementReel" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutChargementReel" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                <label><-></label>
                <input type="text" id="finChargementReel" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finChargementReel" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                <label>Livraison maxi</label>
                <input type="text" id="debutLivraisonMax" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutLivraisonMax" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                <label><-></label>
                <input type="text" id="finLivraisonMax" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finLivraisonMax" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                <label>Livraison réelle</label>
                <input type="text" id="debutLivraisonReelle" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutLivraisonReelle" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                <label><-></label>
                <input type="text" id="finLivraisonReelle" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finLivraisonReelle" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                <label>N° de commande</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="numeroCommande" name="numeroCommande" placeholder="N° Commande">
                <label>Numéro d'OT</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="numeroOT" name="numeroOT" placeholder="Numero OT">
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                <label>Statut</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="statut" name="statut" placeholder="Statut">
                <label>Transporteur</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="transporteur" name="transporteur" placeholder="Transporteur">
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sort').change(function(){
      var valeur = $('#sort option:selected').text();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'MODEL/ajaxSearchThirds.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data, //All the fields data
        success: function(data) {
                   $('tbody').html(data.table);
        }
      });
  })
```

I am a beginner, if you think that what I will do is a bad idea, I am opened to all ideas.

Comment: so where's the ajax and the form?

Comment: *"//Yes but... If the field was blank??"* - So, use a ternary operator? or force them with `!empty()`?

Comment: Ok, so if I force them with !empty(), the user has the right to let this field empty. Suppose that he just want to search by villeChargement, and nohing else, how can i make the request then?

Comment: if you want to give them the option of leaving it empty, then again... use a ternary operator. Those work in almost any language.

Comment: So in JS, or PHP (it doesn't matter because the datas are send from one to each other) I should use ternary operator to give a value if the field is empty and an other value if the field is filled. OK but, in the SQL request, how will I make a request with and only with the filled fields? Should I make a hudge number of condition lines?

Comment: What I suggest is that you assign the POST arrays to variables in ternaries, then use those variables in the query rather than the POST arrays; that should answer your question entirely.

Comment: Sidenote/addendum to the above: Make sure your columns accept NULL values if you wish to use an empty/null default value for the ternaries.

Comment: It's only a SELECT query. So I don't need my columns to accept NULL values in mySQL. Moreover, it could work, if wanted to INSERT new values. Here, I want to display something. So when I will assign a NULL value to my empty variable with ternaries, the result of my request will be nothing. Or I didn't understand something, and I will need your code vision to understand...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310611/sql-ignore-where-cause-if-php-value-is-empty This is what is was exactly searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit hacky answer, but you might find it helpful, my idea is:
just check for empty values in js, and if one is empty - replace it with symbol for any character(% in mysql), then just replace all =: in your query with 'like'

Then your query will return all results for fields that are not empty, but if some are empty, it will accept any value for them. You didn't specify, but i assume that all fields are not null

Comment: You are right. All fields are not null because the javascript event is on change on each field. So, one field must be changed from empty to something to trigger event. This is the best solution that I got on that post. Thank you. However, I will use the solution given above with the link. I just didn't know that you could make a sql query with "WHERE 1" which means "everything is true" for mysql. Thanks again.